# How can I detect if a point is inside a cone or not, in 3D space?

Tags: matlab, c#-4.0, math

How is possible to detect if a 3D point is inside a cone or not?

```
Ross cone = (x1, y1, h1)
Cone angle = alpha
Height of the cone = H
Cone radius = R
Coordinates of the point of the cone = P1 (x2, y2, h2)
Coordinates outside the cone = P2( x3, y3, h3)

Result for point1 = true
Result for point2 = false
```

Comment: What coordinate system? How do you represent the cone?

Comment: A generalization of this (dealing with eliptical cones) is answered at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5799/how-do-i-determine-if-a-point-is-interior-to-an-elliptical-cone

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To expand on Ignacio's answer:

Let

```
x = the tip of the cone
dir = the normalized axis vector, pointing from the tip to the base
h = height
r = base radius

p = point to test
```

So you project `p` onto `dir` to find the point's distance along the axis:

```
cone_dist = dot(p - x, dir)
```

At this point, you can reject values outside `0 <= cone_dist <= h`.

Then you calculate the cone radius at that point along the axis:

```
cone_radius = (cone_dist / h) * r
```

And finally calculate the point's orthogonal distance from the axis to compare against the cone radius:

```
orth_distance = length((p - x) - cone_dist * dir)

is_point_inside_cone = (orth_distance < cone_radius)
```

Comment: I did not know if it is possible to describe more clearly, and with mathematical formula to give me, I'm just not good in English. If you have a photo that would be great.

Comment: The `code` parts of my answer are like mathematical formulas and pseudocode.  I am happy to explain any part in more detail.  Which part do you need help with?

Comment: If you're not familiar with how the dotproduct is used here, this helped me: [link](http://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/dotprod/dotprod.html)

Comment: why can I only upvote this once?! :) this is an extremely clear and concise answer that explains things so much better than all the other resources I looked at.

Comment: Is someone available to explain what's happening inside the pseudo function `length()` in this case?

Comment: this is actually very useful and concise.

Comment: @RobbieS `length(x)` gives the Euclidean norm of a vector `x`.

Answer (score 9):

A cone is simply an infinite number of circles whose size is defined by a linear equation that takes the distance from the point. Simply check if it's inside the circle of the appropriate size.

Answer (score 8):

The language-agnostic answer:

- Find the equation of the line defining the main axis of your cone.
- Compute the [distance from the 3D point to the line](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html), along with the intersection point along the line where the distance is perpendicular to the line.
- Find the radius of your cone at the intersection point and check to see if the distance between the line and your 3D point is greater than (outside) or less than (inside) that radius.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be easier to compute angle between vector to center of cone and vector from apex pointing at point under evaluation.  If vector projection is used and the length of the resultant vector is shorter then the vector pointing at the center of the cone the between the angle and length you know if you are inside a cone.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection