# How to find whether a point in a 3D space lies inside a truncated cone?

Tags: algorithm, math, 3d, vector-graphics

[How can I detect if a point is inside a cone or not, in 3D space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826117/how-can-i-detect-if-a-point-is-inside-of-a-cone-or-not-in-3d-space) will not help because a truncated cone can be a cylinder.

I tried another method which involves too many calculations and is huge.

I'm looking for easier ways to find the presence/absence of a point inside a truncated cone.

```
Mid point of bottom of the truncated cone -> x,y,z
Mid point of top of the truncated cone -> x, y2, z
BottomRadius = r1
TopRadius = r2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it would be sufficient to test for two conditions, which both must be true:

- the point must be above the cone base, and below cone top. A one dimensional test. Use distance from cone base for next step, to be performed only if the result of this step was found to be true.
- the point must be within circumference of the circular cone slice, as determined by the distance from base. Again a relatively simple, also one-dimensional test (distance of point from cone axis compared against slice radius)

Seems pretty straightforward, or am I missing something?

Comment: It was so complicated in my head, but you totally simplified it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the sloppy formulation but I would proceed as follows:

1. Compute the center points c_1, c_2 of both cone circles.
2. Compute a line going through c_1 and c_2
3. Compute the distance of your point p to this line and during this, calculate the point q on the line being closest to p (see the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line))
4. **If q is not between c_1 and c_2**, p lies outside
5. If q is between c_1 and c_2, the distance dist(p,q) has to be smaller than the radius of the cone at point q. Maybe the radius can be calculated something like this: r(q) := dist(q,c_1)/dist(c_1, c_2) * r_1 + dist(q,c_2)/dist(c_1, c_2) * r_2 with r_1 being the circle radius at c_1 and r_2 the radius of the other circle.
6. So **if dist(p,q) > r(q)** , the point lies outside

So two conditions have to be tested

Comment: This method is what I specified as "method which involves too many calculations". :)

Comment: I think this describes pretty much the same approach, only in different words.

Comment: It looks only more complicated since I tried to include the actual formulas :-) But Bushmill and I had the same idea so this is an indicator that this might be a good way to do it