# How to limit pan in orbitcontrols, three.js

Tags: three.js

How to limit pan to only screen so that the scene does not move or drag after certain point in orbitcontrols

Comment: See, perhaps, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588594/orbitcontrol-restrict-panning-movement

Answer (score 0):

Define a pyramid (dir, pitchLimit, yawLimit) or a cone (dir, cosLimit) and confine the direction of the camera (or position of camera depending on what exactly you want) within these limits.

Look for a lib that contains the above routines or implement them your self: [How can I detect if a point is inside a cone or not, in 3D space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826117/how-can-i-detect-if-a-point-is-inside-a-cone-or-not-in-3d-space).